# Combine mutiple sheets into one Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks(A & B) that contain multiple sheets.
I need to copy all sheets of information from Workbook A into Workbook B without impacting on originally data of Workbook B.

Any simple code can be applied to this situation via VBA.

Comment: Have a look at Worksheet.Copy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy

Answer (score 0):

This should work. And it will add an (x) at the end of the sheet name in case of one with the same name already exists in workbook B.

```
Sub Worksheet_Copier()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wAPath As String, wBPath As String
    Dim wA As Workbook, wB As Workbook
    
    wAPath = "" 'Full name (Path) of workbook A
    wBPath = "" 'Full name (Path) of workbook B
    
    Set wA = Workbooks.Open(wAPath)
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(wBPath)

    For Each sh In wA.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        sh.Copy After:=wB.Sheets(wB.Worksheets.Count)
    Next

End Sub
```

If you want to close files, just add at the end:

```
wA.Close SaveChanges:=False
wB.Close SaveChanges:=True
```